# Read Oracle and SQL Server databases in same method

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, oracle

I'm writing an application to read the database generated by a third party software. The problem is that this software can use either SQL Server or Oracle databases.

To read it when it's SQL Server, I'm using SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader, etc.

To read it when it's Oracle, I'm using OracleConnection, OracleCommand, OracleDataReader, etc.

Today, for each method that must do a query on the database, I have two versions of it, one for Oracle and one for SQL Server.

The database is really big and complex, so I have dozens of duplicated methods that are basically the same, the only difference is that one is using Sql database classes and the other is using Oracle database classes.

I've tried really hard to think on a way that I do not have to duplicate each method, but didn't get any clue on it yet.

Is there any way to read both types of databases with same classes? Or is there any other way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Data.Common](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common(v=vs.90).aspx) classes. An example [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/ado.net-2.0-factory-classes/). I have written a DAL Library named [karkas](https://github.com/ati-ozgur/Karkas) using these classes which supports following databases.

- SQL Server
- Oracle
- Sqlite

Comment: Thanks. Very nice article and made things a lot cleaner. The library would be nice too, but it's no in english :(

Comment: I am sorry about that, it is written for a Turkish government project.